# How does -m option work in sort command?

Tags: linux, sort, options

As `sort`'s man page says:

```
-m, --merge
    merge already sorted files; do not sort
```

Here are my two simple text files and the result of `sort` command with `-m` option:

```bsh
soroush@pop-os:~/Desktop$ cat a_file.txt 
aa
ff
hh
bb
soroush@pop-os:~/Desktop$ cat b_file.txt 
gg
tt
ss
ii
cc
soroush@pop-os:~/Desktop$ sort -m a_file.txt b_file.txt 
aa
ff
gg
hh
bb
tt
ss
ii
cc
```

I expected to see this output:

```
aa
ff
hh
bb
gg
tt
ss
ii
cc
```

Could anyone explain this behavior please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merging assumes the files are already sorted: "merge already sorted files; do not sort", so will attempt to merge them into alphabetic order.  It is not a simple concatination.  So in your example:

1. aa < gg : print aa, move to the next line in a_file
2. ff < gg : print ff, move to the next line in a_file
3. hh > gg : print gg, move to the next line in b_file
4. hh < tt : print hh, move to the next line in a_file
5. bb < tt : print bb, move to the next line in a_file
6. No a_file left, so print the rest of b_file.